# Destroy created HTMLElement which was not added to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom

Currently I'm working on a game using pixi.js. I implemented utility functions for e.g. wrapping lines or measure the text length of the longest line to use on a `HTMLCanvasElement`. Here's an example of the `getLongestWidth`:

```
static getLongestWidth(lines: string[]): number {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const longestLine = lines.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b, '');
  return context.measureText(longestLine).width;
}
```

I want to keep the 'core' canvas functions independet (`context.measureText` in this example) so you can even use them without providing a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` everytime.

Since performance is a thing I wonder whether/how I should destroy the created canvas. I'm guessing that after the function has finished at least the reference pointing to it will be destroyed and objects without reference will be garbage collected? But the createElement part throws me off. I tried `document.removeChild(canvas)` which of course fails since it was never actively added to the DOM but I'm not sure what's happening in the background. Couldn't find anything in the docs or with Google and I'm kinda afraid of thousands orphan `HTMLCanvasElements` floating around in the background.

I'm sorry if this a super basic question :) Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

Comment: In the code provided, canvas is not a global variable so it should be garbage collected automatically when it is no longer used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to actively remove an object from memory. GC will collect it when there are no references left for that object.

So you can dereference the object by setting, `canvas = null;`.

You can also use a static class object to keep track of the canvas and delete it when done. It's technically the same thing as dereferencing. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```js
class Test {
    private static test: any = 'test';
    public static testFunc() {
        console.log(`deleting: ${Test.test}`);
        delete Test.test;
        console.log(`done deleting: ${Test.test}`);
    }
}

Test.testFunc();
```

In all cases, the GC will collect it from memory in the next cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Recycle the same object ?

```
class test {
    static getLongestWidth(lines) {
      const context = this.ctx;
      const longestLine = lines.slice().sort((a,b)=>a.length - b.length)[0];
      return context.measureText(longestLine).width;
    }
}
test.ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
test.getLongestWidth(["aa","b"]); //5.5615234375
```